# Change default header color of a p:dataTable?

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

I've a p:dataTable, I want to change the default color just of a header, is it possible ?

```
             <f:facet name="header">
                            List of Fone
            </f:facet>
```

Here my entire code:

```
<p:dataTable var="fone" value="#{fonePersistBean.listInfofone}" paginator="true" rows="10"
                        id="table"  rowStyleClass="odd-row, even-row">

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Lista de fones
                        </f:facet>

                        <p:column headerText="Tipo" sortBy="#{fone.contact}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{fone.contact}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="DDD" sortBy="#{fone.ddd}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{fone.nuDdd}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column >
                             <h:commandLink action="#{foneBean.searchFone(fone)}" >  
                                <i class="cus-find"></i> 
                            </h:commandLink>  
                        </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try CSS using .ui-datatable-header if you wish to change all dataTables. For specific tables, you can use a styleClass attribute for the specific dataTable

Comment: Thanks very much indeed for your answer !

Comment: In the end it is, client side, all html, css and javascript. Learn to become friends with your browser developer tool.